# Can I use a declared variable in VBA inside a cell inside a spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, vba, variables

So if i declared a variable and name it 'Rate1' in the VBA for the sheet im working on. How can I use it in a formula inside a cell in spreadsheet:
Example:

(cell A2)   =A1 * Rate1

Comment: AFAIK you can't do that. What you can do though, is in your formula, use an empty cell somewhere and name that cell `Rate1` via the Range Name manager.  Or just use your VBA to create a named range called `Rate1` that has that value.

Comment: Not if it's strictly a VBA variable. If you create it as a defined name, then you can use it in the cell and in a formula. (Instead of assigning a cell or a range to a defined name, it would effectively be a constant.)

Comment: Im teribly sorry, I did not see this reply. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can access from the worksheet are public functions in modules.  If you need to expose internal values to the worksheet like that, one option is to make a simple wrapper function:

```
'In a Module
Private Const Rate1 As Double = 1.234

Public Function ModuleGlobal(varName As String) As Variant
    Select Case varName
        Case "Rate1"
            ModuleGlobal = Rate1
        'etc.
    End Select
End Function
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
=A1 * ModuleGlobal("Rate1")
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply